# Google Maps API ovverrideStyle does not update polygon color until data refreshes

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I have a right-click event on each polygon, generated from a file and saved in `mapData = map.Data();`

This also includes layer control for each layer, determined by the return from `event`.

At the moment the right-click event should simply change the colour of the polygon and an attribute associated. eg. if `green` make `red` else make `green`

```js
thisLayer.addListener('rightclick', function (event) {
         removeInfoWindows(Layer);
         var color;
         if (event.feature.f.Enabled === 0) {
             color = '#006301';
             event.feature.f.Enabled = 1
         } else {
             color = '#630900';
             event.feature.f.Enabled = 0
         }
         thisLayer.overrideStyle(function (event) {
             return {
                 fillColor: color,
                 strokeWeight: 2
             };
         })
     })
```

Everything works fine, but nothing is updated on the map. From the console I can see the `event.feature.f.Enabled = 1` changes successfully and even when requested at a later stage that attribute is updated, but the colour does not update u̶n̶l̶e̶s̶s̶ ̶I̶ ̶c̶a̶l̶l̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶p̶o̶l̶y̶g̶o̶n̶/̶l̶a̶y̶e̶r̶  unless I call the event from said polygon, that refreshes the data's display...thus changing the polygons' colour correctly. This can continue on with numerous polygons not updating until they are individually clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it: `event.feature`

```js
thisLayer.addListener('rightclick', function (event) {
         removeInfoWindows(Layer);
         var color;
         var stroke;
         if (event.feature.f.Enabled === 0) {
             color = '#006301';
             stroke = 4;
             event.feature.f.Enabled = 1
         } else {
             color = '#a8a8a8';
             stroke = 1;
             event.feature.f.Enabled = 0
         }
         thisLayer.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
             fillColor: color,
             strokeWeight: stroke
         });
     })
```